# How to pad a text file in Linux with extra linefeeds at the end of every line?

Tags: unix

I would like the pad every line of a Linux text file with a space (newline character, etc).  For example, if I have a file containing the following lines:

```
line01
line02
line03
```

I would like it to result in the following:

```
line01

line02

line03
```

I have tried to use the following [`lam`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/lam/) command to do it:

```
lam sourcefile.txt  -s  \n\n  >  resultfile.txt
```

However it only appends the actual characters "nn" rather than the linefeed characters.

```
line01nn
line02nn
line03nn
```

I’ve tried enclosing them in quotes as well, but it didn’t make a difference. How to have it actually insert Linux linefeeds? Or is there a better command to do it?

Comment: You can use sed to do a substitution: `sed -E -e 's/\n/\n\n/g' < filename`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That didn't work for me though.  I'm using a mac.

Comment: @Mark+ the line read by `sed`'s default loop never includes the newline. Instead do `sed 's/$/\n/'` to add at the _end of line_.

Comment: For me that also just appends an "n" at the end of each line rather than an escape character.

Comment: Not that it really matters, but the word "Unix" was changed to "Linux" in this post for some reason.  My question was for a Mac, but I also use Linux as well.  Anyway, thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/$/\
/' sourcefile.txt > resultfile.txt
```

Comment: That's a strange one with the two lines.. It did work though, thank you!